# how to rearrange each block into a column vector?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

example: I have an image,it's size 512X512pixel,then i have splited it into 8x8 blocks.Now i would have 64x64 blocks.Now how to rearrange each block 8x8 into column vector so that the dimension would be 64x4096pixel without inbuilt function "im2col".please help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the shape of your split 64x64 blocks currently? Is it a 4-D array?

Comment: @Navan currently i have 64x64 blocks and it is 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

```
x=rand(512,512);
xi=mat2cell(x,8*ones(1,64),8*ones(1,64));
xii=cellfun(@(x)reshape(x,1,64),xi,'UniformOutput',false);
y=cell2mat(xii);
```